# (C++) Code seems to be operating off the wrong loop...?

Tags: c++

I've been playing around with some code in my down-time from my degree and I've nested a do{}while() loop inside another one but the problem I'm having is that the code keeps going until the last van is full, even after the number of parcels has been fulfilled...

The code's below.  If someone could take a look at it and tell me what I've done wrong that'd be awesome.  Bare in mind I've only really been coding in C++ for about a month so I've still got hella lot to learn..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char cBeltFull;
int iVanCount, iParcelCount, iParcelLoaded;
float fHeaviestVanWeight, fParcelWeight, fCurrentPayload, fVanCapacity;
char cExit = 'N';

int main() {

    iVanCount = 1;
    iParcelLoaded = 1;
    fHeaviestWeight = 0;
    fVanCapacity = 410;


    do {
        //Get the number of parcels to dispatch
        cout << "How many parcels need sending?" << endl;
        cin >> iParcelCount;

        do {
            fCurrentPayload = 0;

            do {

                //Get parcel weight
                cout << endl << endl << endl << "What is the weight the parcel " << iParcelLoaded << "?";
                cin >> fParcelWeight;

                //'Load' the parcel
                cout << endl << endl << "Parcel loaded";
                iParcelLoaded ++;

                //Update the payload
                fCurrentPayload = fCurrentPayload + fParcelWeight;

            } while ((fCurrentPayload + fParcelWeight)) < fVanCapacity)

            //Dispatch the van
            cout << endl << endl << "Van dispatched.";

            //Update the van count
            iVanCount ++;

            if (fCurrentPayload > fHeaviestVanWeight) {

                //Update the heaviest weight
                fHeaviestVanWeight = fCurrentPayload;

            }

        } while (iParcelLoaded <= iParcelCount);

        cout << endl << endl << endl << "Vans dispatched: " << iVanCout;
        cout << endl << endl << "Weight of heaviest van: " << fHeaviestWeight;

        cout << endl << endl << endl << "Exit?  Y for YES or N for NO." << endl;
        cin >> cExit;

    } while (cExit == 'N');

}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? :) Also, where is `fHeaviestWeight` declared?

Comment: Nested do-while loops, that's something I haven't seen in a long time.

Comment: @Borgleader for good reason :D

Comment: I want to get it so it only does the parcel adding bit for as many parcels as the user enters.  At the moment, it keeps going past that until the van's full before it stops which isn't what I wanted to happen...

Comment: `fHeaviestWeight` was a typo, meant to be `fHeaviestVanWeight`.

Comment: In your parcel loading bit (your inner most do-while loop) you tell it to keep going until the van is overweight. You probably want to add to that while condition, also checking the number of parcels in case you run out before having too much weight.

Comment: `((fCurrentPayload + fParcelWeight)) < fVanCapacity)` has one unbalanced bracket. Please post the real code!

Comment: Remove `thanks`, and replace it with a description of what your code does, and what you want it to do, and why they are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
} while (((fCurrentPayload + fParcelWeight)) < fVanCapacity);
```

to this

```
} while (((fCurrentPayload + fParcelWeight)) < fVanCapacity
          && iParcelLoaded < iParcelCount);
```

That way you will load as many items the user inputs. You code contains many syntax errors.

I corrected them for you, but please be more careful next time you post.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char cBeltFull;
int iVanCount, iParcelCount, iParcelLoaded;
float fHeaviestVanWeight, fParcelWeight, fCurrentPayload, fVanCapacity;
char cExit = 'N';

int main() {

    iVanCount = 1;
    iParcelLoaded = 1;
    fHeaviestVanWeight = 0;
    fVanCapacity = 410;


    do {
        //Get the number of parcels to dispatch
        cout << "How many parcels need sending?" << endl;
        cin >> iParcelCount;

        do {
            fCurrentPayload = 0;

            do {

                //Get parcel weight
                cout << endl << endl << endl << "What is the weight the parcel " << iParcelLoaded << "?";
                cin >> fParcelWeight;

                //'Load' the parcel
                cout << endl << endl << "Parcel loaded";
                iParcelLoaded ++;

                //Update the payload
                fCurrentPayload = fCurrentPayload + fParcelWeight;

            } while (((fCurrentPayload + fParcelWeight)) < fVanCapacity && iParcelLoaded < iParcelCount);

            //Dispatch the van
            cout << endl << endl << "Van dispatched.";

            //Update the van count
            iVanCount ++;

            if (fCurrentPayload > fHeaviestVanWeight) {

                //Update the heaviest weight
                fHeaviestVanWeight = fCurrentPayload;

            }

        } while (iParcelLoaded <= iParcelCount);

        cout << endl << endl << endl << "Vans dispatched: " << iVanCount;
        cout << endl << endl << "Weight of heaviest van: " << fHeaviestVanWeight;

        cout << endl << endl << endl << "Exit?  Y for YES or N for NO." << endl;
        cin >> cExit;

    } while (cExit == 'N');

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and corrections.  I'll be sure to take more care in future. :)

Comment: You are welcome @OllyJohn. It's a good practise to accept an answer good enough for your question so that the question appears as answered in the news feed. I see you got -2 in your question, that's because your code had typos, missing semicolons and parentheses, but mostly because it wasn't clear what you wanted to achieve (I had to asked you in the comments). Just some tips, glad I helped solving the issue! :)